# PHP shopping cart with laravel - quantity issue

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I am working on a laravel-shopping site project, and I have problems with the quantity of the product in the cart. 
I am relatively new to Laravel, so things gets more complicated for me...
The thing is that I can't really loop (and look for) simular products in a effective way.

But when I press the "Add to cart"-button, this function will run:

```
public function cart(Product $product){

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // If Cart is empty, add a new array in the session
    if ($cart == []) {
        $cart[] = $product;
        session()->put('cart', $cart);
    }else{
        // else if not empty, loop the cart and look if similar product is in the cart.
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($cart); $i++) {

            $array_cart = json_decode($cart[$i], true);
            if ($product->id == $array_cart["id"]) {
                    $array_cart["id"] += 1;
            }else{
                $cart[] = $product;
                session()->put('cart', $cart);
            } 
        }
    }

    return back();
}
```

The products are objects, and I am not sure how to loop to find the id of the product to match the array-products id. I tried json_decode() to see if that would make it into an array, but I might be wrong here because when I return the value it was the same "object". For example a single product in the cart can look like this:

```
    [{"id": 4,
"name": "HP Desktop",
"description": "Ordinary desktop",
"category": "Desktop",
"price": 1,
"views": 63,
"created_at": "2016-04-11 14:42:58",
"updated_at": "2016-05-27 09:12:59"
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a foreach loop, this will loop through all the objects.

So for example you can run this code in a `controller` to get the `id`:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    dump($product->id);
}
```

Or you can use this in a `blade view`.

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    dump($product->id);
@endforeach
```

---

I suggest you to add a `quantity` in your object, than you can update the `quantity` and calculate the price.

```
public function cart(Product $product){

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // If Cart is empty, add a new array in the session
    if ($cart == []) {
        $cart[] = $product;
        session()->put('cart', $cart);
    }else{
        // else if not empty, loop the cart and look if similar product is in the cart.
        foreach ($cart as $product_item) {
            if ($product->id == $product_item["id"]) {
                    $product_item["quantity"] += 1;
                    $found = true;
            }
        }

        if($found !== true) {
             $cart[] = $product;
             session()->put('cart', $cart);
        }
    }

    return back();
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: I want to thank you so much! I want to upvote, but I need 15 reputation for that.
But thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem mate! Maybe you have in a few days 15 reputation (2 more)! Work for it!

Comment: But actually there was a small problem that I encountered. There was an error "Undefined variable $found", I tried to fix it myself, but didn't have the skill to do it.

Comment: If you use if(!isset($found) && $found !== true) than it will check if the variable exist